# Getting " unexpectedly found nil" error when setting "self imageView! image" in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, dictionary

I am getting the above error in this collection view-detail view code.

`Detail VC`:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView?

    var photo: NSDictionary?

    var image1:UIImage = UIImage()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    //downloadFromUrl(url)
    if let photo = photo {
        let url1 = (photo["images"]!["thumbnail"]!!["url"])! as! String
        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: url1 as String)!
        //print(url)
        downloadFromUrl(url)
    }


}


      func downloadFromUrl(url: NSURL) {
    //self.imageView.hnk_setImageFromURL(url)
    let config:NSURLSessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session:NSURLSession = NSURLSession(configuration: config)
    let request:NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    let task = session.downloadTaskWithRequest(request) { (location, response, error) -> Void in

        let data:NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: location!)!
        let image:UIImage = UIImage(data: data)!

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                self.image1 = image
                print(self.image1)

                self.imageView.image = self.image1

        })
    }


    task.resume()


}        

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

And here is some methods in `collection VC`:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PhotosViewCell

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()

    cell.photo = self.photos[indexPath.row] as? NSDictionary

    //self.p = self.photos[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
    //print("Link is \(cell.photo!["link"]!)")

    return cell
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let p = self.photos[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
    let VC:DetailViewController = DetailViewController()
    VC.photo = p

    self.presentViewController(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I know I am probably getting this error because ***viewDidLoad()*** is not yet ready but what is the solution and I do need this dictionary inside ***viewDidLoad()*** because I need to call that ***downloadFromUrl()*** method.

Oh, I am not using ***prepareforsegue()*** method. tried that too, maybe I was doing wrong.
In the debug area, I am getting the following:

```
 2016-01-06 13:30:55.075 AuthCheck[3623:74910] Warning: Attempt to present    <AuthCheck.DetailViewController: 0x7ff103dfb6c0> on <AuthCheck.PhotosViewController: 0x7ff103c2fd90> whose view is not in the window  hierarchy!
  <UIImage: 0x7ff103cd1820>, {150, 150}
  fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Which means correct image is being downloaded but it is not being able to set to imageView's image property. No idea why?
Will someone tell me the solution please?

Comment: Have you tried to print p in the collectionViewController?

Comment: try print it after the `let p = self.photos[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary` line

Comment: can I you paste the method `numberOfRows`?

Comment: @abarbier  it works in Collection VC but I need that in Detail VC because I need to set the image property of imageView through downloadFromUrl() method. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a runtime error because you are force-unwrapping an optional that happens to contain no value (i.e., it is `nil`). Please check your optionals before unwrapping (it is good practice):

```
print(photo!) // <--Dangerous

if let photo = photo {
    print(photo) // <--Safe
}
```

...unless your code path makes it 100% sure that the optional **does** contain a value.

You are downloading data from the internet; that should typically be an asynchronous operation, because it takes significant time and you don't want to freeze your main thread (user interface) while it completes.
So you need to perform it on the background, and use the obtained data inside a **completion handler** (i.e., block or closure).

Comment: That worked but I have just updated the code inside Detail VC. My main problem started when I tried to set the image of imageView to the image downloaded from web but it also showed "unexpectedly found nil".

Answer (score 0):

`ViewDidLoad()` is called when the view controller is loaded, meaning that **it happens when you create the instance, before you present the view controller**

```
// viewDidLoad() is called right here
let VC:DetailViewController = DetailViewController()
// this happens after you try to print photo
VC.photo = p
```

This means that your optional variable `photo` is still null when you print it. To avoid the error, you could unwrap the variable with

```
if let photo = photo {
    print(photo)
}
```

Although this wouldn't help you accomplish your goal. So, **do your tasks in `viewDidAppear` rather than `viewDidLoad`, which is called after the view becomes visible.**

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()

    print(photo!)
    downloadFromUrl(url)
}
```

Or, if you need to do the task before the view appears, **create a separate function in `DetailViewController` and call it after assigning VC.photo.**

```
func task() {
    print(photo!)
    downloadFromUrl(url)
}
```

then in CollectionView, do

```
let p = self.photos[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
let VC:DetailViewController = DetailViewController()
VC.photo = p
VC.task()
```

Comment: "ViewDidLoad() is called when the view controller is loaded, meaning that it happens when you create the instance". Actually, no. `viewdidLoad()` is called when you access the `view` property of the vc and it has not yet been initialized (the view is initialized lazily, only when it is needed for the first time). That typically happens just before the vc is presented on screen, but you can trigger it manually by either accessing the `view` property setter or by calling `loadView()` (not recommended).

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting "unexpectedly found nil" error on self.imageView!.image = image line now . I used viewDidAppear() too but still getting the error.

Comment: Again, this is because your VS's view has not loaded. self.imageView at this point is still nil.

Comment: actually now think of it, why don't you call the download session while you are still in CollectionVC and update your DetailVC with an UIImage? I think that might work better

Comment: I tried doing that too but still getting the same error. Either that or I am  missing something.  Plus, I am also getting this warning: Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Actually a safer way to do it is to call  downloadFromUrl(url) from the didSet method like this :

```
var photo: NSDictionary = NSDictionary() { 
   didSet {
       // your code to get the url here you can test if photo is nil
       downloadFromUrl(url)
   }
}
```

But this is not the problem here. Since you don't use the storyboard to initialise your viewController (let VC = DetailViewController()) you never instantiate the content of your viewController (for exemple the imageView)

Comment: I have tried to do this before. It also gives the same error in imageView.image line.

Comment: Ok so maybe your imageView is nil because you never init it. since you don't use the storyboard it is never allocated you must do self.imageView = UIImageView() in the viewDidLoad to avoid this error

Comment: A better way would be to actually use the storyboard to instantiate your detailViewController like this : let VC:DetailViewController = UIStoryboard(name:storyboard name).instanciateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier)

Comment: I am using Storyboard

Comment: To actually use the storyboard you must instantiate your view controller like this : let VC:DetailViewController = UIStoryboard(name:storyboard name).instanciateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier).
Else you just create an instance of DetailViewController without using the storyboard

Comment: To be sure implement the method awakeFromNib in your detailViewController and verify that this function is called. If not the content of your view is never initialised by the storyboard

Comment: called awakeFromNib() and verified it. View is initialized but I am still getting the error.

Comment: Can you write the line where you got the NSException and the log?

Comment: Ok,I'll dothat tomorrow

Comment: I have edited the code again. Maybe, this will clear up my problem.

Comment: And tried that Storyboard solution again. Didnt get any error this time but imageView is still not being set.

Comment: Ok so that's good. Do you get an error when setting the image?

Comment: Also tried to hard code the image in Main.Storyboard by adding image in xcassets. That works but when i try setting image theough code, then no image comes on imageView. Its empty.

Comment: no error at all. No "unxpectedly found nil" error but the imageView is empty.

Comment: Forgot 1 thing. Although I am not getting error but I am still getting warning: "whose view is not in window hierarchy". The one that I have added in Question at the last. "PhotosViewController.swift" is the master collection VC file. "AuthCheck" is name of app.

Comment: The image is not empty? Did you try to set the image from xcasset from the code (instead of downloading the image)

Comment: Yes and that works. But not with the code and the downloaded image. I also have "PhotosViewCell.swift". It totally works for in that file while downloading images for all the cells. But when I press any cell, it should be showing that particular image in Detail VC. That's basically what I want.

Comment: Try to move the downloadFromUrl in the viewdidappear method

Comment: Ok, but I just changed "modal" view to "show" and it is now working. No idea why.

Comment: 1 more thing, whenever Detail View shows. It shows that "back/AuthCheck" button for a second and then navBar disappears. I can manually implement that back button, but do you know why is it happening. I used Storyboard() method. Anyways, Thanks for taking out your time for this problem.

Comment: Try to move back to modal (just to check if it was a storyboard problem that you fixed by modifying it). Do you manually hide the nav bar? Do you use a navigationController or add your navigationBar manually?

Comment: Tried that and the problem comes again. It goes away with show segue. As for navBar, I am not adding it manually. It comes automatically with show segue. Isnt it? And currently(with "show" segue), it is working but there is a warning: Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged.

Comment: Now I used UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController!.presentViewController() instead of self.presentViewController() and the warning is gone. Although that navBar is still disappearing.

Comment: You should have a navigation controller in your storyboard with your collectionVC as rootviewcontroller

Comment: If I do that, navBar wont even appear in Collection VC.